# Figure out which word of the form is the longest?

Tags: javascript, html, find

So i have a form in my html that just lets people type in whatever they please. Now in my javascript i need to make it so when you press the button it returns the longest word in the phrase they typed into the form. I had to make a version of this earlier that counted the vowels and I'm assuming i can just edit that somehow to instead see what the longest word is.

Here is my html,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='p3-vowels.js'></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp" id = "demo_form">
    Phrase: <input type="text" name="CheckLongest" value="Put Phrase Here">  <br>
    <input type="button" id = "btn1" value="Check for Longest Word">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my JS currently coded to count the vowels.

```
function vow(form) {
  var a = form.CountLongest.value;
  flag = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    switch (a[i].toLowerCase()) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      flag++;
      break;
    }
  }
  alert(flag);
}

function init() {
    var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1")
    button1.onclick = function() {
      vow(document.getElementById('demo_form'));
    };
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: $('#btn').click(function(){
      var data = $("textarea" ).val().split(" ");
      data = data.sort(function(a, b){return b.length-a.length});
      alert(data[0]);
});     demo here https://jsfiddle.net/bdellinger/45Lnp5xc/

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/bjn8fap7/1/, can't post anything since this is closed, but might as well give you what I had done. This is pretty similar to Suman's answer, though, just that I integrated it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below method.

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });
    return word;
}
console.log(longestWord("Figure out which word of the form is the longest"));
```

Comment: um would this be the entire js? or would this just replace the top part

Comment: this is method, you can use it directly like longestWord("Figure out which word of the form is the longest");